# grep range of numbers

Tags: bash, count, grep

For the following text I need to count the lines that the number between parenthesis is in the range [10-20].

```
    This function's cyclomatic complexity is too high. (1)
    This function's cyclomatic complexity is too high. (2)
    This function's cyclomatic complexity is too high. (3)
    This function's cyclomatic complexity is too high. (4)
    This function's cyclomatic complexity is too high. (5)
    This function's cyclomatic complexity is too high. (6)
    This function's cyclomatic complexity is too high. (7)
    This function's cyclomatic complexity is too high. (8)
    This function's cyclomatic complexity is too high. (9)
    This function's cyclomatic complexity is too high. (10)
    This function's cyclomatic complexity is too high. (12)
    This function's cyclomatic complexity is too high. (13)
    This function's cyclomatic complexity is too high. (14)
    This function's cyclomatic complexity is too high. (15)
    This function's cyclomatic complexity is too high. (16)
    This function's cyclomatic complexity is too high. (17)
```

Im trying the following commands:

```
cat log.txt | grep -c "This function's cyclomatic complexity is too high. ([10-20])"
cat log.txt | grep -c "This function's cyclomatic complexity is too high. ([10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,20])"
```

But didnt work. Whats the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep -c "(1[0-9])\|(20)" filename
```

Answer (score 1):

`grep` is the wrong tool.  You don't want to be using a regex to do numerical comparison.  Try:

```
awk "/This function's cyclomatic complexity is too high./"'$2 >= 10 && $2 <=20 {c++} END {print c}' FS='[()]' pruebascript.txt
```

Note that you probably can simplify to:

```
awk '$2 >= 10 && $2 <=20 {c++} END {print c}' FS='[()]' pruebascript.txt
```

depending on your actual data.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have access to a terminal so this is untested, but try `cat pruebascript.txt | grep -c "This function's cyclomatic complexity is too high. (1[0-9]|20)"`. Your regular expression in grep asks for 1 or 2, and 2 or 0.

1[0-9] will match anything between 10 to 19 as well as 20.

Read more about numeric ranges regex:
https://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

Answer (score 1):

To list distinct strings for `grep` you surround them with `\(\)` and separate with `\|`, like this:

```
$ grep "This function's cyclomatic complexity is too high. (\(10\|11\|12\))" file
This function's cyclomatic complexity is too high. (10)
This function's cyclomatic complexity is too high. (12)
```