# How to get number in range 10-20 in grep

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I need from this file extract line that starts with a number in the range 10-20 and I have tried use grep "[10-20]" tmp_file.txt, but from a file that has this format

```
1.
2.
3.
4.
5.
6.
7.
8.
9.
10.aa
12.bbb
13.cccc
14.ddddd
15.eeeeee
16.fffffff
17.gggggggg
18.hhhhhhhhh
19.iiiiiiiiii
20.jjjjjjjjjjj
21.
```

it returned everything and marked every number that contains either 1, 0, 10, 2, 0, 20 or 21 :/

Comment: `sed -n '/^10\./,/^20\./p' tmp_file.txt`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47330069/grep-range-of-numbers

Comment: is the file guaranteed to be sorted numerically by the first column?

Comment: grep is for finding text patterns, not for determining numeric values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An other one with awk

```
awk '/^10\./,/^20\./' tmp_file.txt

awk '/^10\./,/^13\./' tmp_file.txt
10.aa
12.bbb
13.cccc
```

Answer (score 4):

With an extended regular expression (`-E`):

```
grep -E '^(1[0-9]|20)\.' file
```

Output:

```
10.aa
12.bbb
13.cccc
14.ddddd
15.eeeeee
16.fffffff
17.gggggggg
18.hhhhhhhhh
19.iiiiiiiiii
20.jjjjjjjjjjj
```

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
grep -w -e '^1[[:digit:]]' -e '^20' tmp_file.txt
```

- `-w` forces matches of whole words.  That prevents matching lines like `100...`.  It's not POSIX, but it's supported by every `grep` that most people will encounter these days.  Use `grep -e '^1[[:digit:]]\.' -e '^20\.' ...` if you are concerned about portability.
- The `-e` option can be used multiple times to specify multiple patterns.
- `[[:digit:]]` may be more reliable than `[0-9]`.  See [In grep command, can I change [:digit:] to [0-9]?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/276253/264812).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the file might not be sorted and using numeric comparison

```
awk -F. '$1 >= 10 && $1 <= 20' < file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

grep is not the tool for this, because grep finds text patterns, but does not understand numeric values.  Making patterns that match the 11 values from 10-20 is like stirring a can of paint with a screwdriver. You can do it, but it's not the right tool for the job.

A much clearer way to do this is with Perl:

```
$ perl -n -e'print if /^(\d+)/ && $1 >= 10 && $1 <= 20' foo.txt
```

This says to print a line of the file if the beginning of the line `^` matches one or more digits `\d+` and if the numeric value of what was matched `$1` is between the values of 10 and 20.